# Como usar o middleware auth no Laravel 8 corretamente?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Pessoal criei esse grupo de rotas para certas páginas do meu projeto serem protegidas pelo middleware auth:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', [AuthController::class, 'loginPage'])->name('login');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
        Route::get('home', [AuthController::class, 'home'])->name('home');
    });
});
```

Porém quando verifico a lista de rotas o middleware não foi aplicado à rota home:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo de errado?

E está seria a melhor forma de fazer este processo?

Comment: No print das rotas tem o middleware auth. Não entendi. Abre uma sessão anônima do navegador e tenta acessar a rota home, se estiver ok, não deve carregar a página/view referente a rota home
Veja outra maneira de usar o middleware groups aqui https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#middleware-groups

Comment: A forma como você protegeu a rota está correta. Além disso, pelo que vi no screeshot, o middleware está sendo aplicado.

Chegou a verificar se consegue acessar sem estar logado?
Tenta fazer logout ou acessar essa mesma rota com num outro navegador ou aba anônima. Aparentemente está tudo ok.